# Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. UseEffect hook issue

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, infinite-loop

I have stored data into the localStorage. I have used useEffect hook to get the data from localStorage to a useState hook. I have use the state as a dependency of useEffect hook. After doing that, It is running an infinite loop that I can see in the console. Actually I want to refresh the UI when the state is update. Could you help me to do that?

**My code:**

```
const [chatLog, setChatLog] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setChatLog(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("chatLog")));
  }, [chatLog]);
```

I want to update the UI when the state get new value.

Comment: Very curious why did you put `chatLog` inside depsArray of useEffect hook? " }, [chatLog]);" this part. That means every time `chatLog` is changed - hook is reexecuted. Changing `chatLog` again. And again. Just remove it?

Comment: Every time the local storage item is parsed a new object is created.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you need 'chatLog' as a dependency or maybe rephrase what you want to achieve?

Comment: Because UI is not updating every time chatLog is getting new value.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to use `useEffect`. Try with `useMemo` like this:

```
const chatLog = useMemo(()=>{
     return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("chatLog"));
},[])
```